# Unknown Host -Unable to locate the server named "Server1" .The server does not have DNS entry Error in SP 2013 SP1

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, central-administration, windows-server

I have installed `SP 2013 SP1` on my development server and `Central Admin` was created successfully.
But when I navigate to the `Central Admin` or any web application url[`root site collection` & other sites] am getting the below  error:

> Unknown Host -Unable to locate the server named "Server1" .The server does not have DNS entry Error.Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.

My OS is `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

[image: DNS ISSUE UNKNOWN HOST]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add a DNS entry for SharePoint server. For more detailed information, you could refer to the article below.

The article below is about adding a New DNS Host Record in Windows Server 2012 DNS Server.

http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1954305/adding-dns-host-record-windows-server-2012-dns-server.html

if you have a DNS entry and then if you face the same error, then try below option,

Please un-check proxy tick from internet options --> Connections --> LAN Settings --> Use a proxy server.

It worked for me